# Mass frequency problem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, solid-state-physics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, dispersion

For [Dispersion relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) , according to Gaussian profile, the author in the [equation 3 wrote as](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922)
$\omega= \left(k^2+\omega_{mass}^2\right)^{1/2}$ 
My question is what is mass frequency and how it arose in the frequency term?

Comment: Maybe you should read the article in which they say the full derivation of eq 3 is done.

Comment: I didn't get you!

Comment: [Ref](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9503217) Equation (22) page 9

Comment: got it but why did they call it mass frequency?